# AuthorizationMiddlewareResultHandler not being called

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am trying to implement the code under Handling the AuthorizationFailureReason found [here](https://khalidabuhakmeh.com/customize-the-authorization-pipeline-in-aspnet-core) to customize the not authorized error messages depending upon the page.

In the logs I see that the FailHandler is being hit and the authorizationFailureMessage is set to "You are not eligible for this service at this time." At this point it redirects to /Account/AccessDenied.  It never hits the AuthorizationMiddlewareResultHandler code.

In my startup.cs file

```
using IAuthorizationMiddlewareResultHandler = MyCompany.IAuthorizationMiddlewareResultHandler;


        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {

...
            services.AddAuthentication(sharedOptions =>
            {
                sharedOptions.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                sharedOptions.DefaultChallengeScheme = WsFederationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            })

            .AddWsFederation(options =>
            {
                options.ClaimsIssuer = claimsIssuerServer;
                options.Wtrealm = _wtrealm;
                options.MetadataAddress = _metaAddress;             

                options.Events.OnRedirectToIdentityProvider = Authentication.OnRedirectToIdentityProvider(claimsIssuerServer, identityProviderServer);
                options.Events.OnSecurityTokenReceived = Authentication.OnSecurityTokenReceived(_audience, validIssuerServer, signingKey);

                options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidAudience = _audience,
                    ValidateIssuer = true,
                    ValidIssuer = validIssuerServer,
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                    IssuerSigningKey = signingKey,
                };
                options.RequireHttpsMetadata = true;

            }).AddCookie(cookieoption => {
                cookieoption.Cookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.Always;
                cookieoption.EventsType = typeof(CustomCookieAuthenticationEvents);
            });

            services.AddScoped<CustomCookieAuthenticationEvents>();

            services.AddRazorPages(options =>
            {
...              
            })
            .AddMvcOptions(o => o.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter())); 

            services.AddAuthorization(options =>
            {
...
                options.AddPolicy("AuthorizedUser", policy =>
                {
                    policy.Requirements.Add(new FailRequirement("AuthorizedUser"));
                });
            });

...
            services.AddTransient<IAuthorizationHandler, FailHandler>();
            services.AddSingleton<IAuthorizationMiddlewareResultHandler, AuthorizationMiddlewareResultHandler>();

            services.AddScoped<IClaimsTransformation, AddRolesClaimsTransformation>();
        }


        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {

...
            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();

...

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapRazorPages();
            });
        }
    }
}
```

---

On the Create.cshtml.cs page the user tries to access i have

```
[Authorize("AuthorizedUser")]
public class CreateModel : PageModel
{
```

---

AuthorizationMiddlewareResultHandler.cs  (this is the code that is never hit)

```
public class AuthorizationMiddlewareResultHandler : IAuthorizationMiddlewareResultHandler
{
    private readonly ILogger<AuthorizationMiddlewareResultHandler> _logger;
    private readonly Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.Policy.AuthorizationMiddlewareResultHandler _defaultHandler = new();

    public AuthorizationMiddlewareResultHandler(ILogger<AuthorizationMiddlewareResultHandler> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public async Task HandleAsync(
        RequestDelegate next,
        HttpContext context,
        AuthorizationPolicy policy,
        PolicyAuthorizationResult authorizeResult)
    {
        var authorizationFailureReason = authorizeResult.AuthorizationFailure?.FailureReasons.FirstOrDefault();
        var message = authorizationFailureReason?.Message;
        _logger.LogInformation("Authorization Result says {Message}",
            message
        );

        if (authorizationFailureReason?.Handler is FailHandler)
        {
            var html = $"<html><h1>{message}</h1></html>";
            context.Response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status403Forbidden;
            await Results.Content(html, "text/html").ExecuteAsync(context);
        }
        else
        {
            // Fall back to the default implementation.
            await _defaultHandler.HandleAsync(next, context, policy, authorizeResult);
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
public class FailHandler : AuthorizationHandler<FailRequirement>
{
    protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(
        AuthorizationHandlerContext context,
        FailRequirement requirement)
    {

        string permission = requirement.RequiredPermission.ToString() ?? "";

        string authorizationFailureMessage = "You are not authorized for this page.";

        if (!context.User.HasClaim(c => c.Type == "Permission" && c.Value == permission))
        {
            switch (permission)
            {
                case "AuthorizedUser":
                    authorizationFailureMessage = "You are not eligible for this service at this time.";
                    break;
            }

            context.Fail(new AuthorizationFailureReason(this, authorizationFailureMessage));
        }
        else
        {
            context.Succeed(requirement); 
        }        


        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

---

FailRequirement.cs

```
public class FailRequirement : IAuthorizationRequirement
{

    public FailRequirement(string requiredPermission) 
    { 
        RequiredPermission = requiredPermission;
    }

    public string RequiredPermission { get; set; }

}
```

---

IAuthorizationMiddlewareResultHandler.cs

```
public interface IAuthorizationMiddlewareResultHandler
{
    Task HandleAsync(
        RequestDelegate next,
        HttpContext context,
        AuthorizationPolicy policy,
        PolicyAuthorizationResult authorizeResult);
}
```

---

I see the authentication scheme was forbidden errors in the logs below.  I'm not sure if that is having any impact on this issue.  Authentication in the app is working fine.

> {"@t":"2023-01-26T19:04:15.7618707Z","@mt":"Authorization failed. {Reason}","Reason":"Fail() was explicitly called.","EventId":{"Id":2,"Name":"UserAuthorizationFailed"},"SourceContext":"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.DefaultAuthorizationService","RequestId":"80000044-0005-fe00-b63f-84710c7967bb","RequestPath":"/internship/create","ApplicationName":"MyApp","Environment":"Development"}
> {"@t":"2023-01-26T19:04:15.7653501Z","@mt":"AuthenticationScheme: {AuthenticationScheme} was forbidden.","AuthenticationScheme":"Cookies","EventId":{"Id":13,"Name":"AuthenticationSchemeForbidden"},"SourceContext":"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationHandler","RequestId":"80000044-0005-fe00-b63f-84710c7967bb","RequestPath":"/internship/create","ApplicationName":"MyApp","Environment":"Development"}
> {"@t":"2023-01-26T19:04:15.7654538Z","@mt":"AuthenticationScheme: {AuthenticationScheme} was forbidden.","AuthenticationScheme":"WsFederation","EventId":{"Id":13,"Name":"AuthenticationSchemeForbidden"},"SourceContext":"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.WsFederation.WsFederationHandler","RequestId":"80000044-0005-fe00-b63f-84710c7967bb","RequestPath":"/internship/create","ApplicationName":"MyApp","Environment":"Development"}
> {"@t":"2023-01-26T19:04:19.9125753Z","@mt":"{HostingRequestFinishedLog:l}","@r":["Request finished HTTP/2 GET https://localhost:44386/internship/create - - - 302 - - 9840.7917ms"],"ElapsedMilliseconds":9840.7917,"StatusCode":302,"ContentType":null,"ContentLength":null,"Protocol":"HTTP/2","Method":"GET","Scheme":"https","Host":"localhost:44386","PathBase":"","Path":"/internship/create","QueryString":"","HostingRequestFinishedLog":"Request finished HTTP/2 GET https://localhost:44386/internship/create - - - 302 - - 9840.7917ms","EventId":{"Id":2},"SourceContext":"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics","RequestId":"80000044-0005-fe00-b63f-84710c7967bb","RequestPath":"/internship/create","ApplicationName":"MyApp","Environment":"Development"}
> {"@t":"2023-01-26T19:04:19.9188021Z","@mt":"{HostingRequestStartingLog:l}","@r":["Request starting HTTP/2 GET https://localhost:44386/Account/AccessDenied?ReturnUrl=%2Finternship%2Fcreate - -"],"Protocol":"HTTP/2","Method":"GET","ContentType":null,"ContentLength":null,"Scheme":"https","Host":"localhost:44386","PathBase":"","Path":"/Account/AccessDenied","QueryString":"?ReturnUrl=%2Finternship%2Fcreate","HostingRequestStartingLog":"Request starting HTTP/2 GET https://localhost:44386/Account/AccessDenied?ReturnUrl=%2Finternship%2Fcreate - -","EventId":{"Id":1},"SourceContext":"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics","RequestId":"80000046-0005-fe00-b63f-84710c7967bb","RequestPath":"/Account/AccessDenied","ApplicationName":"MyApp","Environment":"Development"}

Comment: in case anyone out there is curious.  I removed the WSFederation authentication code and replaced it with '''            services.AddAuthentication(a =>
            {
                a.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                a.RequireAuthenticatedSignIn = false;
            }
            ).AddCookie();''' and although the forbidden error is now gone the handler is still not hit.